# Block Access While Updating?

Tags: php, auto-update

I am creating a PHP update script which will replace most files in the main directory (index.php) and others!

I am just wondering if during the update someone tries to access the website what would happen? Do I have to setup a .htaccses to block all connections to index.php?

OR

I can just leave it be and let the update finish.

Comment: how long does the update take? how popular is the site? are there security issues? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to block access to the website until the update finishes. there are multiple ways to implement this, but since this is a php question do the following.

in the index.php check for a file called maintenance.flag
when it is present reroute to a different index (like index.maintenance.php)

in the different index you appoligise for the inconvinience etc.

when you want the update pushed, just create the empty maintenance.flag. when the update is finished delete the flag file

Comment: But the index page is being updates itself. So if the index is being accessed while being updated it wouldn't be able to redirect. Thanks

Comment: your index needs to be able to handle the update and route the error. rebuild it to support this feature

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a normal website. Say said website has half of its files required to operate arbitrarily deleted. What would happen? The website would be missing elements or would flat out stop working.

So yes you should put a temporary landing page up during the update, although if your site does not experience regular usage, it may not be a major concern.